# Importing Eclipse workspace from Windows to Mac OS X Mavericks?

Tags: java, eclipse, macos

When I open my workspace on a windows pc, the debugger shows no errors and the programs in my workspace run well. However, when I import my workspace to Eclipse on my Macbook Pro running `OS X Mavericks 10.9.2`, the IDE goes crazy and marks everything with errors.

Some examples:

Importing java.util.Scanner; causes the error: `The import java.util cannot be resolved`

Declaring a Scanner causes the error: `Scanner cannot be resolved to a type`

What is going on and what steps can be taken to resolve these unexplained import errors?

Comment: You sure it's a java project and you have a jdk defined?

Comment: Check in `Preferences > Java > Installed JREs` to see if Eclipse knows about a JDK. If not add one.

Comment: Yes i have the latest JDK installed and it is selected. It is really strange because i can transfer workspaces between different windows computers. I guess its the OS cross that messes things up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't typically share workspaces across filesystems like this, especially across platforms.  I'm really not surprised it blew up.

You **can** share Projects, though.  First, create a new workspace on the new computer.  Then copy the Project (the folder that contains the .project file) from the old to the new workspace.  In Eclipse, choose the 'Import Existing Project' option and you're done.